# Survey Page - Spacing bug

Tags: html, css

I created a survey page that show the results in a table using 3 colors.
It looks like this:
[image]
and this is the code of the table:

```
                // Create an HTML table element to display the survey results
                survey = "<table style='margin:0px auto;' dir='ltr'>";

                // Add a row to the table for the Original category, with an image whose width corresponds to the value in the w array
                survey += "<tr><td style='text-align: center; background-color: gray;'>Original</td>";
                survey += $"<td width='500' style='text-align: left; height:calc(100% + 4px);'><img src='Images/Red.png' height='50px' width='{w[0]}'></td></tr>";

                // Add a row to the table for the Prequel category, with an image whose width corresponds to the value in the w array
                survey += "<tr><td style='text-align: center; background-color: gray;'>Prequel</td>";
                survey += $"<td style='text-align: left; height:calc(100% + 4px);'><img src='Images/Yellow.png' height='50px' width='{w[1]}'></td></tr>";

                // Add a row to the table for the Sequel category, with an image whose width corresponds to the value in the w array
                survey += "<tr><td style='text-align: center; background-color: gray;'>Sequel</td>";
                survey += $"<td style='text-align: left; height:calc(100% + 4px);'><img src='Images/Green.png' height='50px' width='{w[2]}'></td></tr>";

                survey += "</table>";
```

The problem is that there is a space in the lower and upper side of each color, it does not fill all the height...

someone know how to fix it?

I tried to put in each `<td>` `height = "100%"` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please post the code as text and not as image

Comment: try `<td style="height:calc(100% + 4px)"></td>`

Comment: can you make [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe reset border of image `<img src='Images/Red.png' height='50px' width='...' style='border:0;'>` or set border-color of image to red.